# Is not authorized to perform an operation while I have the full access of an aws service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-lambda

I have created a simple nodejs script to handle the files in S3, and I want it to be executed on lambda. My admin has added me in IAM with full access to lambda and S3. However, when I select the "S3 execution Role" as my role, AWS banned this operation and gave me an error:

```
 is not authorized to perform: iam:PutRolePolicy on resource: role s3_exec_role
```

Why is that? Does this means I also need some other access?

Comment: it means while you have access to S3 and lambda you don't have access to IAM for PutRolePolicy - i.e you are trying to modify the IAM role s3_exec_role and access is denied

Comment: That make sense now.

Comment: @LingboTang I had the same problem can you explain how you solve it?

Comment: @AbdulHameed I think so, I'll give you a brief answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sum1sAdmin is correct, you don't have access to change `IAM` and `PutRolePolicy` which will have the higher authorization than `s3_exec_role`, what this error implies is that, you are trying to do an operation `add a "role" to myself` which need `iam:PutRolePolicy` as your permission. This is nothing related s3 or lambda. Add it yourself or ask your admin to add this for you, then you should be good to go.